# First table format error in List of Tables

Tags: table-of-contents

I have a 31-page thesis and have a problem with the list of tables. 5 out of 6 tables are listed in the section but the first table just has "10table.1" which is nonsense. I checked the code but it is similar to other tables. What do you think is the problem here? Thank you so much! [image]

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\caption{Distribution of financial misconduct cases by year\footnote{Year refers to the initial investigation of the crime by SEC}}\\ [1ex]
\begin{tabular}{|| l | c | l | c ||}
\hline
Year &  Number of cases & Year  & Number       of cases \\ [0.5ex]
\hline\hline
1999    & 3 & 2010  & 9\\
\hline
2000    & 5 & 2011  & 7\\
\hline
2001    & 3 & 2012  & 5\\
\hline
2002    & 11    & 2013  & 6\\
\hline
2003    & 12    & 2014  & 7\\
\hline
2004    & 8 & 2015  & 5\\
\hline
2005    & 10    & 2016  & 14\\
\hline
2006    & 10    & 2017  & 5\\
\hline
2007    & 17    & 2018  & 20\\
\hline
2008    & 9 & 2019  & 17\\
\hline
2009    & 14    & 2020  & 16\\
\hline
\end{tabular}\\ [1ex]

Source: AAER
\label{table:1}
\end{table}
```

---

The only problem with my code is the footnote. Everything else is fine.

Comment: you presumably have an error in the caption for that table,  but if you show no code it will be hard to suggest how to fix it

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm sorry. I've added the code.

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided a real test but if I complete your example to a document

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\listoftables

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\caption{Distribution of financial       misconduct cases by year\footnote{Year refers to the initial investigation of the crime by SEC}}\\ [1ex]
\begin{tabular}{|| l | c | l | c ||}
\hline
Year &  Number of cases & Year  & Number       of cases \\ [0.5ex]
\hline\hline
1999    & 3 & 2010  & 9\\
\hline
2000    & 5 & 2011  & 7\\
\hline
2001    & 3 & 2012  & 5\\
\hline
\end{tabular}\\ [1ex]

Source: AAER
\label{table:1}
\end{table}  

\end{document}
```

I get

```
! Argument of \@caption has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.9 ...initial investigation of the crime by SEC}}
                                                  \\ [1ex]
?
```

If you get *any* error the pdf output such as you show is not intended to be usable, just a debugging aid.

You do not want a footnote in the list of tables so

```
\caption
 [Distribution of financial misconduct cases by year]
 {Distribution of financial misconduct cases by year\footnote{Year refers to the initial investigation of the crime by SEC}}
```

You then get

```
! LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.11 ...tial investigation of the crime by SEC}}\\
                                                   [1ex]
?
```

from the misplaced `\\`  delete those

It then runs without error but it is better not  to use numeric `\label` so `\label{table:misconduct}`

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\listoftables

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\caption
 [Distribution of financial misconduct cases by year]
 {Distribution of financial misconduct cases by year\footnote{Year refers to the initial investigation of the crime by SEC}}
\begin{tabular}{|| l | c | l | c ||}
\hline
Year &  Number of cases & Year  & Number       of cases \\ [0.5ex]
\hline\hline
1999    & 3 & 2010  & 9\\
\hline
2000    & 5 & 2011  & 7\\
\hline
2001    & 3 & 2012  & 5\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

Source: AAER
\label{table:misconduct}
\end{table}  

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The footnote seems to be disappearing.  How important is it to put the `\label` close to the `\caption`?  (In other words, what other things can come between that would mess up the label?)

Comment: It looks like a `\vspace{.5ex}` is wanted after the caption.

Comment: Thank you, Sir!